# Showing that $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} |u_k|^2}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k| \leq n\cdot\max\{|u_k|:1\leq k \leq n\}$

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

My textbook has used the following inequalities without any proof:

Let $X=\Bbb R^n$, then

$$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n} |u_k|^2}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|  \leq n\cdot \max\{|u_k|:1\leq k \leq n\} \leq n\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|^2}.$$

The second inequality is obvious. But I am struggling with others.

Comment: Isn't the inequality between the leftmost and the rightmost parts obvious as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|\right)^2{=\sum_{k,l=1}^{n}|u_k|\cdot|u_l|\\=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|^2+\sum_{k,l=1\\k\ne l}^{n}|u_k|\cdot |u_l|\\\ge \sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|^2}$$therefore $$\sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}|u_k|$$

Answer (score 0):

The right-most inequality holds since 
$$|u_k|\leq\max\{|u_i|, 1\leq i\leq n\}$$
for every $k$ so that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|u_k|\leq\sum_{k=1}^n \max\{|u_i|\}=n\max\{|u_i\}$$
since we sum a constant.

To prove the left-most inequality, note that it is enough to prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |u_k|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |u_k|\right)^2$$
which should be fairly obvious if you expand the right-hand side.